# trying to server's DNS but keep getting 8.8.8.8

Tags: linux, dns

I am working for client who had another developer before that had all his information.

the only thing he has is SSH access which i am not too experienced with.

I am trying to find out the DNS so i can point several domains to that sever.

So in command line i typed the following:

```
sudo grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
sudo /etc/resolv.conf
less /etc/resolv.conf
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

All of them return

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

which is google public DNS. How can that happened ?

Comment: all these commands do the same thing only with different names. that does not change the content of resolv.conf

Comment: well i was googling - how can i get my DNS through shell. the above example came. i am not server savvy.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Find out whats the server's DNS are. so i can point domains  to them..

Comment: i dont't understand that part `so i can point domains to them`. how do you intend to do that? them being the DNS?

Comment: i would go to godaddy, and set the DNS

Comment: this is totally unrelated. the DNS you see in resolv.conf are the servers used by the host to resolve other domains.

Comment: well mti said to use ifconfig to find the server's address i will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this means that the server was using Google's public DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for DNS.  But, from your question, it sounds like what you want is the server's public IP address, so that you can point DNS records for your domains so that server.  To find the server's public IP address, use the `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am looking for.i am unfamiliar with the ifconfig command i will search for that.